# count of selected radio buttons in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

suppose I have groups of radio buttons like so:

```
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="rdQueen" /> Scaramouche</label> <br />
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="rdQueen" /> Will you do the</label> <br />
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="rdQueen" /> Fandango</label> <br />
```

... sometime later in the page ...

```
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="rdFruit" /> Mango</label> <br />
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="rdFruit" /> Kiwi</label> <br />
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="rdFruit" /> Potato</label> <br />
```

All I want to do is make sure atleast one of them from both group has been selected.. so I need to count the radiobuttons that have been checked, in this case it'll be 2.

Only, I am not sure how to do that. help please!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To check for only those specific groups:

```
$(':radio[name="rdQueen"]:checked, :radio[name="rdFruit"]:checked').length;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/HzfKq/

Comment: great, thanks, if that is your real picture, tell me how to get muscles like that please!

Comment: I know it works without quoting the attribute values, but the docs require it. This leaves the door open for jQuery to start requiring a more strict adherence to that rule which may break some code without calling it a "breaking change".

Answer (score 11):

You could do:

```
 var numberOfCheckedRadio = $('input:radio:checked').length
 //this gives you the total of checked radio buttons on the page
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`checked-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to get the ones that are checked, and the [`length`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property to find out how many there were.

```
alert( $('input:radio:checked').length );
```